# How to change loadingText on a Panel with Sencha Touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I'm using setLoading(true) on a Panel, but cant find a way to change the "Loading..." text below the spinner.

I need at least to translate it to Norwegian.

```
app.views.ForfallDetaljerView = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
    id: 'forfalldetaljer',
    scroll: 'vertical',
    dockedItems: [ new app.views.BackToolbar({
        title: 'Detaljer',
        buttonHandler: function(){
            Ext.dispatch({
                controller: app.controllers.forfallDetaljer,
                action: 'back',
            });
            // Clear view
            app.views.forfallDetaljer.update('');
        }
    })],
});

app.myview = new ForfallDetaljerView();
app.myview.setLoading(true);
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Question asked 5 hrs ago, 2 responses within 1 minute of each other.  Such is life on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.myview = new ForfallDetaljerView();
var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(app.myview.el, {msg: "<text here>"});
mask.show();
```

You can then do a `mask.hide()` when you want to remove it.

You could also do something like:

```
var l = app.myview.setLoading(true);
l.el.down('div.x-loading-msg').setHTML("<text here>");
```

So hopefully these two options point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'll try the l.el.down(...).setHtml() way. Ext.LoadMask occupy the whole screen, and not only the panel that i want to cover. I have a toolbar at top and bottom that should not be masked.

Comment: @PHP_Jedi Your welcome, the area of the mask is determined by the element you pass into it (in my answer the whole app.myview panel), if you pass in the element of the body panel, without the toolbar, it will only mask that.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to show the loading message:

```
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});
myMask.show();
```

Both Panel.setLoading(true) and Ext.LoadMask(...) return a LoadMask object.  So it should work similarly.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.LoadMask